# Confidence interval for Bagging method in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, confidence-interval, bagging

Here is the code which implements bagging that I copied from net (http://www.r-bloggers.com/improve-predictive-performance-in-r-with-bagging/) :

```
set.seed(10)
y<-c(1:1000)
x1<-c(1:1000)*runif(1000,min=0,max=2)
x2<-c(1:1000)*runif(1000,min=0,max=2)
x3<-c(1:1000)*runif(1000,min=0,max=2)
```

As you can see, y is a sequence of the values from 1 to 1000. `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` are permutations of `y`, but with random errors added. `runif` generates a specified number of random numbers from 0 to 1, unless a min and max are specified, in which case the numbers fall between those values. Each of the x sequences will roughly approximate y, but with random errors thrown in. The set.seed function is simply to ensure that the subsequent random number generation proceeds in a predictable fashion, so that your results match mine.

Fitting a linear model to the variables results in an R squared of .7042:

```
lm_fit<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3)
summary(lm_fit)
```

Now we will see how well the x values predict y. First, we designate a random sample of y to be our “test” set. The rest will be the training set.

```
set.seed(10)
all_data<-data.frame(y,x1,x2,x3)
positions <- sample(nrow(all_data),size=floor((nrow(all_data)/4)*3))
training<- all_data[positions,]
testing<- all_data[-positions,]
```

The above code places all of our variables into a data frame, then randomly selects 3/4 of the data to be the training set, and places the rest into the testing set.

We are now able to generate predictions for the testing set by creating a linear model on the training set and applying it to the testing set. We are also able to calculate the prediction error by subtracting the actual values from the predicted values (the error calculation here is root mean squared error):

```
lm_fit<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3,data=training)
predictions<-predict(lm_fit,newdata=testing)
error<-sqrt((sum((testing$y-predictions)^2))/nrow(testing))
```

The calculated error should be 161.15.

The next step is to run a function that implements bagging. In order to do this, I will be using the foreach package. Although I will not use it in parallel mode, this code is designed for parallel execution, and I highly recommend reading my post about how to do it if you do not know how.

```
library(foreach)
length_divisor<-4
iterations<-1000
predictions<-foreach(m=1:iterations,.combine=cbind) %do% {
training_positions <- sample(nrow(training),           
size=floor((nrow(training)/length_divisor)))
train_pos<-1:nrow(training) %in% training_positions
lm_fit<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3,data=training[train_pos,])
predict(lm_fit,newdata=testing)
}
predictions<-rowMeans(predictions)
error<-sqrt((sum((testing$y-predictions)^2))/nrow(testing))
```

The above code randomly samples 1/4 of the training set in each iteration, and generates predictions for the testing set based the sample. It will execute the number of time specified by iterations. When iterations was set to 10, I received an error value of 161.10. At 300 iterations, error went to 161.12, at 500 iterations, error went to 161.19, at 1000 iterations, error went to 161.13, and at 5000 iterations, error went to 161.07. Eventually, bagging will converge, and more iterations will not help any further. However, the potential for improvement in results exists. You should be extremely cautious and assess the stability of the results before deploying this approach, however, as too few iterations or too large a length divisor can cause extremely unstable results. This example is trivial, but this can lead to better results in a more “real-world” application.

1) How to rank in sequence  Training and Testing in a column ?

2) How can I have 95% Confidence interval for each predicted value ?